# Why is my ExecuteScalar<bool> returns false even though the query execution is success?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, dapper

I'm new at SQL Server.
I'm currently working on simple ATM simulation program just for practice, and I want to check whether the transfer is success or not (and by the way, I'm using Dapper ORM).

The code will be executed when I click the transfer button, here's some piece of the code:

```
try
{
    var balance = sqlcon.ExecuteScalar<float>("GetClientBalance", pinParam, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    if (balance < transferAmount)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: Your balance is not enough to transfer", "Transfer Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    else
    {
        var success = sqlcon.ExecuteScalar<bool>("TransferMoney", transferParam, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        if (success)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Transfer Success! You just transfer to " + lblDesName.Text + " for " + lblAmount.Text, "Transfer Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(success.ToString());
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

The `success` variable is always `false` even though the stored procedure (`TransferMoney`) runs successfully. I'm afraid I just made a silly mistake here.

Edit: This is the query of `TransferMoney` stored procedure:

```sql
USE [Stellar]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROC [dbo].[TransferMoney]
@PIN varchar(6),
@DestinationNumber varchar(20),
@Amount float
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Client.Cards
    SET Balance -= (@Amount + 0.5)
    WHERE PIN = @PIN

    UPDATE Client.Cards
    SET Balance += @Amount
    WHERE Client.Cards.CardNumber = @DestinationNumber

    UPDATE Client.Cards
    SET LastTransaction = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
    WHERE PIN = @PIN
END
```

Thanks!

Comment: what is output value of sp`TransferMoney`?

Comment: value of `success` depends upon output of your store procedure.

Comment: @RahulAgarwal The query is added, maybe I made some mistake here?

Comment: @JohnWoo I added the query, still don't understand why `success` returns `false`

Answer (score 0):

Per MSDN :

```
cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

> If the first column of the first row in the result set is not found, a
>   null reference is returned. If the value in the database is null, the
>   query returns DBNull.Value.

In your case, store procedure does not result any result and generic version of ExecuteScalar must be trying parsing result to T, in your case which is always false.